# Does Photoshop CC still have Bristle Brushes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I remember back in CS6 I loved using [bristle brushes](http://www.peachpit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Five-More-Adobe-Photoshop-Tips-in-Five-Days-Tip-1--Customizing-Bristle-Brushes-for-Calligraphy&WT.rss_f=AuthorBlog&WT.rss_a=Five-More-Adobe-Photoshop-Tips-in-Five-Days-Tip-1--Customizing-Bristle-Brushes-for-Calligraphy&WT.rss_ev=a), but I haven't seen them since. Does Photoshop CC still have them? Or is there a way to load them in?

I have looked around and cannot find them among brush/tool presets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh never mind, curse of asking, you find answers once you post. According to [this link](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1664592) they are called `bristle tips` not bristle brushes. They are legacy brushes, so to get them in Photoshop CC one needs to simply go to the top right corner drop down menu of the `brushes presets menu` and select `legacy brushes` as [recommended here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2430905).